# Angular passing parameters to route cannot match routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to navigate to a component which should take in 2 url parameters but for some reason I get an error saying that routes cannot be matched

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path: 'home/:dataClass',
    },
    canActivate: [ProtectedRoutesGuard],
    component: DataViewerRouteComponent,
},
{ // PROBLEM ROUTE BELOW

    path: '/:dataClassName/:id',
    data: {
        name: 'Service Status'
    },
    component: DataViewerRecordsComponent,
},
{ 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    path: '',
    data: {
        name: 'Service Status',
        module: ['data-viewer']
    },
    canActivate: [ProtectedRoutesGuard],
    component: DataViewerHomeComponent,
},
{
    pathMatch: 'full',
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/data-viewer',
}
```

];

The navigation is as follows:

```
this.router.navigate([this.dataClassName + '/' + this.id]);
```

The route is being populated with the expected values but it is not being matched to any routes.
Error message as follows:

```
core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'benchmarks/101723102'
```

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'required/1234'

Comment: what if you have a proceeding slash, like `navigate(['/' + this.dataClassName + '/' + this.id])`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Unfortunately not. Tried it and produces the same error. I am thinking the issue is in the routes[] where I might not be declaring properly

Answer (score 0):

your routing should probably look like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/'+this.dataClassName], {queryParams: {'id': this.id}});
```

and then you need to parse the queryParams from the component that you route to.

Answer (score 0):

**navigateByUrl**

You could use [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl) when you are navigating using a string.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${this.dataClassName}/${this.id}`);
```

**navigate**

Otherwise when you are using [navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate), you need to provide the url-segments ( the parts separated by `/` )

```
this.router.navigate([`/${this.dataClassName}`, this.id]);
```

*Sidenote: You may not want to use parameters only in your route*

*PS: If I recall correctly you should not define a Route starting with `/`*